# Overriding QAbstractItemModel::index and accessing std::map

Tags: c++, qt

In my program I want to use view/model pattern with view = QListView and my own model which I subclassed from QAbstractListModel. My data class looks like

```
class Avtomat
{
...
 map<QString, State *> states;
...
};
```

In my model class

```
class AvtomatModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
    ...
    Avtomat a;
    ...
};
```

I'm trying to overload QAbstractItemView::index function so that I'm able to provide interface for editing data map. 
As index function takes int row argument I solved that problem by providing the following

```
State* Avtomat::pStateFromIndex(int index) const
{
    map<QString, State *>::const_iterator i;
    int count = 0;
    for (i = states.begin(); i != states.end() && count != index; ++i)
        ++count;
    return (*i).second;
}
```

so in my index function I do like this

```
return createIndex(row, column, a.pStateFromIndex(row));
```

but that seems pretty ugly because I have O(n). Can you help me to design a better way to access my map using int index?

Answer (score 2):

This is a fundamental data modelling issue. What's the primary way you need to retrieve your data? By key or by index?

If you only ever access it by index (including in the model) then you're simply using an inappropriate data structure and should switch to something else like a list.

If you do need to query by key too then you have several options. There's nothing wrong with what you're doing already if efficiency isn't a huge driver, especially if the data set is small. Alternatively you could also maintain both key and index mappings to your underlying data. This is a simple and effective solution but it means you have to take the hit of managing consistency between the two and has a memory overhead which may be significant if your data set is large. Or you could use a data structure that provides access by both key and index directly. Ultimately it depends on your specific circumstances and the data domain you're working with.

There's a good [summary](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/containers.html) of the Qt container classes (along with the std containers) in the documentation. The section on [algorithmic complexity](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/containers.html#algorithmic-complexity) may be particularly interesting to you.

Answer (score 1):

The other option is to use a vector to hold the data in key-value pairs.  The vector can then be accessed by index or by key.
Disadvantage of this is that inserting into a vector is expensive relative to a std::map.

```
typedef std::pair<QString, State*> StateP;
typedef std::vector<StateP> States;
States states;
```

Then maintain the vector in sorted order based on a predicate that compares the first element.  You can the lookup items by index in O(1) or key in O(log n).

```
struct StatePCompare {
    bool operator()(StateP const& lhs, StateP const& rhs) const {
        return (lhs.first < rhs.first);
    }
};

void Avtomat::insert(QString key, State* state) 
{
    States::iterator i = std::lower_bound(states.begin(), states.end(), StatePCompare());
    if ((i != states.end() && (i->first == key)) {
        // key already exists, set the element
        i->second = state;
    }
    else {
        states.insert(i, state);
    }
}

State* Avtomat::find(QString key) 
{
    States::iterator i = std::lower_bound(states.begin(), states.end(), StatePCompare());
    if ((i != states.end() && (i->first == key)) {
        return i->second;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```